# Why does pairs exist?

Tags: lua

I'm sure many of you already know that the pairs function just returns next, t, and nil. What is the point of this? I've heard some say it's for readability but I think it just confuses people about the structure of a for loop.

So why does it exist?

Comment: It's a tool in the tool box, use it if you think it gets the job done, or don't. You may learn that using that can reduce the length of your code significantly in some cases, and therefore make it easier to read.

Comment: Wrong.  It returns `next`, `t`, and `nil` *or* calls the `__pairs` metamethod.

Comment: Do you want to start teaching people to write `for k, v in next, t, nil` instead of `for k,v in pairs(t)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua 5.2, the `__pairs` and `__ipairs` metamethods were added to allow tables to have custom iterators. Not only that, but it's easier to read. There's also a `__next` metamethod as of Lua 5.2.

[Reference](http://lua-users.org/wiki/GeneralizedPairsAndIpairs)